# How to change theme layout in Opencart?

Tags: php, layout, content-management-system, themes, opencart

Help me on how do i change the layout theme for opencart. I want to have my layout of my site. Thank you. I've tried changing the CSS but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you add a new theme for your site? Which css file did you edit?

Comment: This question is better suited for OpenCart forums on how to manage the store theme/layout. It has no programmatic concern at all. Therefore it is considered as Off Topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. First of all, check, are you which is theme layout using in your store?
   Go to Admin > System > Settings > Edit your store > Store Tab > & then check, you are which template selected here. (default or any other template..)
2. Go to your site source > catalog > view > theme > default(the previously selected template) > stylesheet > & then you can modify stylesheet.css file. (you will changes in stylesheet.css files according to default OpenCart theme. but, if you have used any other custom template. so You will need to check & find right CSS file.)