# css changes not applying in custom template in opencart

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

i'm new to opencart. my opencart version is 2.0

i have made changes in stylesheet.css file but changes are not affecting.
also i made changes in .tpl files that changes are affecting but in css file color, background color, and styles are not affecting

my css file shown below:

```
 body 
{
     background: #e5e5e5; /* #b6b7bc; */
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Lucida Grande", "Segoe UI", Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;/* 'Open Sans', sans-serif; */
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #696969;/* #666; */
    font-size: 0.80em; /*12px; */
     margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    line-height: 20px;
}

/* menu */
#menu {
    background-color: Gray; /* #229ac8; */
    /* background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #23a1d1, #1f90bb);
    background-repeat: repeat-x; */
    border-color: Gray Gray transparent; /* #1f90bb #1f90bb #145e7a; */
    min-height: 40px; 
}
#menu .nav > li > a {
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
    min-height: 15px;
    background-color: Gray; /* transparent; */
}
```

i commented default color's and applied my own color's but changes are not applying...

help me for this problem

thanks in advance

Comment: I think, You need to remove your browser cache and then check it.

Comment: thanks for ur replay... i already tried this one but still not working..

Comment: Please Read this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23627357/how-to-change-theme-layout-in-opencart/23629961#answer-23629961

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that you are changing the correct css file in the template folder.
Check the source of the css file by viewing view source in browser and verify.

Also verify that the css file is included if not include it

```html
$this->document->addStyle('catalog/view/theme/' . $this->config->get('config_template'). '/stylesheet/' . $css_file);
```

Comment: thanks for ur replay..my problem solved. what my mistake is i didn't change the path in header.tpl.. now it's working fine thank you...